# How to use BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT with substructures?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-fusion

For instance, suppose I have the following struct/sub-struct definition:

```
struct address_rec
{
  std::string  m_street;
  std::string  m_state;
  unsigned     m_zip;
};

struct employee_rec
{
  std::string  m_name;
  address_rec  m_address;
};
```

How should I use `BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT` on `employee_rec`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adapt both structs, it also helps to break your grammars down into each struct types too, (a rule for address and a rule for employee which contains the address rule)

```
struct address_rec
{
  std::string  m_street;
  std::string  m_state;
  unsigned     m_zip;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    ::address_rec,
    (std::string, m_street)
    (std::string, m_state)
    (unsigned, m_zip)
)

struct employee_rec
{
  std::string  m_name;
  address_rec  m_address;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    ::employee_rec,
    (std::string, m_name)
    (address_rec, m_address)
)
```